# CSV is actually .... Semicolon Separated Values ... (Excel export on AZERTY)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv

I'm a bit confused here.

When I use Excel 2003 to export a sheet to CSV, it actually uses semicolons ...

```
Col1;Col2;Col3
shfdh;dfhdsfhd;fdhsdfh
dgsgsd;hdfhd;hdsfhdfsh
```

Now when I read the csv using Microsoft drivers, it expects comma's and sees the list as one big column ???

I suspect Excel is exporting with semicolons because I have a AZERTY keyboard. However, doesn't the CSV reader then also have to take in account the different delimiter ?

How can I know the appropriate delimiter, and/or read the csv properly ??

```
    public static DataSet ReadCsv(string fileName)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string pathName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
        string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection
        (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties=Text;");
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM " + file, excelConnection);
            OleDbDataAdapter excelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(excelCommand);
            excelConnection.Open();
            excelAdapter.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }
        finally 
        {
            if(excelConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed )
                excelConnection.Close();
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to just use a [decent CSV library](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com); one that lets you specify the delimiter:

```
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader("yourinputfile.csv"))
{
    csvReader.ValueSeparator = ';';
    csvReader.ReadHeaderRecord();

    while (csvReader.HasMoreRecords)
    {
        var record = csvReader.ReadDataRecord():
        var col1 = record["Col1"];
        var col2 = record["Col2"];
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a great library ... Can we use this in a commercial application ? We couldn't make that out from the license ... Also, do you need an attribution in our "About" window, and what would that have to be ? Thanks for your answer and for sharing your library.

Comment: Absolutely - the license is about as permissive as they come. No need for credits - your upvote here is sufficient :) But if you really like it, a review on the codeplex site would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately we are targeting .NET 2.0 and cannot add a reference to the KBCsv lib. We tried to open the source code project, but we only have VS2003 & VS2008. Is there a version for .NET 2.0 available? Or am I missing something maybe?
Thanks a lot though  :-)

Comment: I removed official .NET 2.0 support just because I wanted to reduce my time commitments. But since you want it, I've added a 2.0 build of the latest release for you. See http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/releases/view/36254

Comment: Wow man, you're the best! Thanks. Just for correctness: csvReader.ValueDelimiter = ';'; should be csvReader.ValueSeparator = ';'; for our purpose here. (That gave confusing results at first :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the correction - I've updated my post. Yes, delimiters delimit values that need to be (i.e. values that contain the separator character), and separators, er, separate values.

Answer (score 3):

Check what delimiter is specified on your computer. Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Regional Options tab - click Customize button. There's an option there called "List separator". I suspect this is set to semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

- Solution for **German Windows 10**:

[image: Change Windows system delimiter]

- Mention to change the decimal separator to `.` and maybe thousands separators to   (thin space) as well.

Can't believe this is true...**Comma-separated values** are separated by semicolon?

Comment: Some tools save **Tab-separated values** with `.tsv` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by dendarii, the CSV separator that Excel uses is determined by your regional settings, specifically the 'list separator' character.
(And Excel does this erroneously in my opinion, as it is *called* a comma seperated file)

HOWEVER, if that still does not solve your issue, there is another possible complication:

Check your 'digit grouping' character and ensure that is *NOT* a comma.

Excel appears to revert back to semicolon when exporting decimal numbers and has digit grouping also set to a comma.
Setting the digit grouping to a full stop / period (.) solved this for me.